# squares instead of icons fontawesome

Tags: html, css, sass, fonts, font-awesome

Im trying to add an icon to my web from fontawesome. What I want to do is import it without using cdns.

My html code looks like this:

```
<div class="footer__socialmedia__icons">
  <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
  </i>
</div>
```

My app.scss file looks like this:

```
// Fonts
// =================================================

@import "../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss";
@import "../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss";
@import "../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss";
@import "../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss";
@import "../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/v4-shims.scss";
```

The only way it worked was adding this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

but I really want to keep it localy...

Comment: scss file need to be processed and link to font-family / svg updated to where you uploaded them

Comment: @G-Cyrillus i thought I got it, but I don't - can you explain it with example?

Comment: nop sorry, i would have to download every files to a personnal server and configure it so scss file will be compiled into css at request and it won't help you much . You need yourself to download the whole package from cdns and move it to your server, that means not only the scss processed file, but also font and svg files that are needed

Comment: you should start from here https://fontawesome.com/support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, my problem got solved.
Maybe this will help someone:
All I needed to do was import a js file into my app.js component. In my code it looks like this

```
import '../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all'
```

Cheers